# Foreach array php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this php code, i need to know is it possible `$data`
 objects put as array, I wanna return result as:

```
  Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [rate] => 1 [currencyCode] => USD ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [rate] => 2 [currencyCode] => CAD ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [rate] => 3 [currencyCode] => AUD )...)
```

Now im getting iy without Array.

```
<?php
class testing_model extends CI_Model{
function displayCurrency(){
$array = array();
$data = new stdClass();
$i=0;
$XMLContent=file("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");

foreach($XMLContent as $line){
 if(preg_match("/currency='([[:alpha:]]+)'/",$line,$currencyCode)){
      if(preg_match("/rate='([[:graph:]]+)'/",$line,$rate)){
            //Output the value of 1EUR for a currency code  
               $data->rate =  $rate[1];
               $data->currencyCode =  $currencyCode[1];             
                print_r($data);              
            }   

        }       
    }   
}   
}
```

Comment: dirty solution: $x = (array)$data.

Comment: Try manipulating the data as a Json object? It can act like an array.